# Why is the second JSON object invalid?

Tags: javascript, json

The first result parses $.parseJSON(data) just fine:

```
{"result":{"output":"<table cellspacing=\"0\" cellpadding=\"0\" border=\"0\" id=\"krd_table\" class=\"0\"><tr><th>Agency Name</th><th>Email</th><th>Phone</th><th>Edit</th><th>View</th></tr><tr><td>CLASP Homes - Westport</td><td class=\"item\">me@email.org</td><td class=\"item\">222-222-2222</td><td class=\"item\"><a href=\"/agencies/edit/31\" class=\"edit_row\">Edit</a></td><td class=\"item\"><a href=\"/agencies/view/31\" class=\"view_row\">View</a></td></tr><tr><td>Horizons at Greens Farms</td><td class=\"item\">me@email.org OR mme@email.org</td><td class=\"item\">222-222-2222</td><td class=\"item\"><a href=\"/agencies/edit/67\" class=\"edit_row\">Edit</a></td><td class=\"item\"><a href=\"/agencies/view/67\" class=\"view_row\">View</a></td></tr></table>", "num_results":"2"}}
```

The second however, through the same output and construction results in invalid JSON:

```
{"result":{"output":"<table cellspacing=\"0\" cellpadding=\"0\" border=\"0\" id=\"krd_table\" class=\"0\"><tr><th>Agency Name</th><th>Email</th><th>Phone</th><th>Edit</th><th>View</th></tr><tr><td>Center for Prevention & Recovery - Positive Directions (The)</td><td class=\"item\">me@email.org</td><td class=\"item\">222-222-22224</td><td class=\"item\"><a href=\"/agencies/edit/23\" class=\"edit_row\">Edit</a></td><td class=\"item\"><a href=\"/agencies/view/23\" class=\"view_row\">View</a></td></tr><tr><td>Children\'s Community Development Center</td><td class=\"item\">me@email.org</td><td class=\"item\">222-222-2222</td><td class=\"item\"><a href=\"/agencies/edit/28\" class=\"edit_row\">Edit</a></td><td class=\"item\"><a href=\"/agencies/view/28\" class=\"view_row\">View</a></td></tr><tr><td>CLASP Homes - Westport</td><td class=\"item\">me@email.org</td><td class=\"item\">222-222-2222</td><td class=\"item\"><a href=\"/agencies/edit/31\" class=\"edit_row\">Edit</a></td><td class=\"item\"><a href=\"/agencies/view/31\" class=\"view_row\">View</a></td></tr><tr><td>Horizons at Greens Farms - Westport</td><td class=\"item\">me@email.org OR me@email.org</td><td class=\"item\">222-222-2222</td><td class=\"item\"><a href=\"/agencies/edit/67\" class=\"edit_row\">Edit</a></td><td class=\"item\"><a href=\"/agencies/view/67\" class=\"view_row\">View</a></td></tr><tr><td>Interfaith Housing Association</td><td class=\"item\">me@email.org</td><td class=\"item\">222-222-2222</td><td class=\"item\"><a href=\"/agencies/edit/72\" class=\"edit_row\">Edit</a></td><td class=\"item\"><a href=\"/agencies/view/72\" class=\"view_row\">View</a></td></tr><tr><td>Project Return</td><td class=\"item\">me@email.org</td><td class=\"item\">222-222-2222</td><td class=\"item\"><a href=\"/agencies/edit/103\" class=\"edit_row\">Edit</a></td><td class=\"item\"><a href=\"/agencies/view/103\" class=\"view_row\">View</a></td></tr><tr><td>ITNCoastalCT (formerly CoastalCT Senior Transportation)</td><td class=\"item\">me@email.org</td><td class=\"item\">222-222-2222</td><td class=\"item\"><a href=\"/agencies/edit/164\" class=\"edit_row\">Edit</a></td><td class=\"item\"><a href=\"/agencies/view/164\" class=\"view_row\">View</a></td></tr><tr><td>Kim\'s Agency</td><td class=\"item\">me@email.org</td><td class=\"item\">222-222-2222</td><td class=\"item\"><a href=\"/agencies/edit/189\" class=\"edit_row\">Edit</a></td><td class=\"item\"><a href=\"/agencies/view/189\" class=\"view_row\">View</a></td></tr></table>", "num_results":"8"}}
```

Any ideas why this is happening?
Thanks
Rich

UPDATE:
removed slashes, but it still gets invalidated. Here's is the version without. JSONLint tells me:

```
Parse error on line 3:
...{        "output": '<tablecellspacing="
----------------------^
Expecting 'STRING', 'NUMBER', 'NULL', 'TRUE', 'FALSE', '{', '['




{"result":{"output":'<table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0" id="krd_table" class="0"><tr><th>Agency Name</th><th>Email</th><th>Phone</th><th>Edit</th><th>View</th></tr><tr><td>CLASP Homes - Westport</td><td class="item">me@email.com</td><td class="item">222-222-2222</td><td class="item"><a href="/agencies/edit/31" class="edit_row">Edit</a></td><td class="item"><a href="/agencies/view/31" class="view_row">View</a></td></tr><tr><td>Horizons at Greens Farms - Westport</td><td class="item">me@email.com</td><td class="item">222-222-2222</td><td class="item"><a href="/agencies/edit/67" class="edit_row">Edit</a></td><td class="item"><a href="/agencies/view/67" class="view_row">View</a></td></tr></table>', "num_results":"2"}}
```

**Follow Up**
I figured out the double quotes around the attributes were causing the problems here and needed to be escaped. As everyone pointed out single quotes within the content, should not be escaped and also keys & values need to be surrounded within double quotes.
Thanks for everyone's input.

Comment: You should edit your post to remove all those email addresses and phone numbers.

Comment: You can use http://jsonlint.com/ to check the correctness.

Comment: @Cfreak, thanks for the tip, I removed the numbers and addresses.

Answer (score 3):

You don't need to escape single quotes. Replace `\'` with `'` and you will validate.

Comment: Seems as though the table attributes are causing problems here, since the value are in double quotes. So the attributes need escaping here. Correct?

Comment: well, you changed your quotes again! use double quotes for JSON, not single. So go back to the original, but don't escape the single quotes only and escape the double quotes.

Comment: ah, yeah I've been messing with this for a bit, so the output value is in double quotes, but still returns an error because of the attributes (which are in double quotes). Escaping those makes it valid.

Answer (score 3):

```
Children\'s Community Development Center
```

Don't escape single quotes in a double quoted string.  You have instances of `\'` of that in your string.  Remove the needless `\` and it validates fine.

Answer (score 1):

You are escaping your single apostrophes, don't do that.

Answer (score 1):

I think the issue here is the escaped single quotes in `Kim\'s Agency` and `Children\'s Community Development Center` - these don't need to be escaped, only the double quotes.